# Newsletter layout issues in outlook

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I'm trying to reproduce this Newsletter

[image: the good layout]

But when I send a test to myself the layout gets changed. I've tried to respect the html tables and the inline css but I'm stack. I can't figured it out what I've done wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!
If you find a solution please explain so I know what I have done wrong

[image: the bad layout]

And this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 </head>
<body style="padding: 15px;background-color: #FFF;margin: 0!important;">
    <div class="wrapper" style="width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;">
        <div class="wrapper-inner">

            <table class="outer-table" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Verdana;color: #00467f;font-size: 12px;width: 100%;max-width: 670px;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #FFF;">
                <tr style="height: 60px;">
                    <td class="image" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;height: 200px;">
                        <a href="https://www.cdvi.co.uk/win-trip-paris-0" style="color: #00467f;text-decoration: none;"><img src="header.png" style="width: 100%;max-width: 670px;height: auto;"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr> <!--- End Banner -->
            </table> <!--- End Outer Table -->
            <table class="main-table" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Verdana;color: #00467f;font-size: 12px;width: 100%;max-width: 610px;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #FFF;border-radius: 6px;">
                <tr style="height: 60px;">
                    <td class="one-column" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;">
                        <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Verdana;color: #00467f;font-size: 12px;">
                            <tr style="height: 60px;">
                                <td class="inner-td" style="padding: 10px;text-align: justify;font-size: 13.2px;line-height: 20px;">
                                    <p class="left" style="margin: 0;">To celebrate the launch of our new catalogue, we are giving you the opportunity to win 2 return Eurostar tickets to Paris and 300€ to spend during your trip!</p>
                                <div class="bullet-text">
                                    <p style="margin: 0;">&nbsp</p>
                                    <p style="margin: 0;">As you would expect from CDVI it has every product you need to complete a successful installation. The all new CDVI catalogue has:</p>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>new products for all your access control needs </li>
                                            <li>a new handy size </li>
                                            <li>the online version has links to our products and datasheets</li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                                    <p style="margin: 0;">The competition is free to enter and the winner will be drawn from all entrants after the closing date of 15th August 2018.</p>
                                     <p style="margin: 0;">&nbsp</p>
                                    <p style="margin: 0;">Your Parisian escape is just around the corner!</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr> <!--- End Heading, Paragraph & Button Section -->


            <table class="middle-table" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Verdana;color: #00467f;font-size: 12px;margin: auto;padding-top: 10px;">
                    <tr style="height: 60px;">
                        <td class="flag" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;">
                            <a href="https://www.cdvi.co.uk/win-trip-paris-0" style="color: #00467f;text-decoration: none;"><img src="French_flag.png" style="width: 120px;height: 80px;"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr> <!--- End Banner -->
                </table> <!--- End Outer Table -->


        <table class="main-table" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Verdana;color: #00467f;font-size: 12px;width: 100%;max-width: 610px;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #FFF;border-radius: 6px;">
                <tr style="height: 60px;">
                    <td class="one-column" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;">
                        <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Verdana;color: #00467f;font-size: 12px;">
                            <tr style="height: 60px;">
                                <td class="inner-td" style="padding: 10px;text-align: justify;font-size: 13.2px;line-height: 20px;">
                                    <p class="center" style="margin: 0;text-align: center;max-width: 580px;line-height: 24px;">Download our new Catalogue <a href="https://issuu.com/cdviuk/docs/2018-product-selector_digital2" style="color: #00467f;text-decoration: none;"><strong>here</strong></a></p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="center" style="margin: 0;text-align: center;max-width: 580px;line-height: 24px;">The CDVI group is a worldwide manufacturer of leading edge security  solutions  for  every  installer,  offering  products  ranging from Biometric & Online Access Control, Electromagnetic Locking, Keypads, Stand Alone Entrance Systems to Door Automation. More information about our free in-house training <a href="https://www.cdvi.co.uk/training" style="color: #00467f;text-decoration: none;"><strong>here</strong></a></p>
                                    <p style="margin: 0;">&nbsp</p>   
                                    <p class="center" style="margin: 0;text-align: center;max-width: 580px;line-height: 24px;">Read the terms and conitions <a href="https://www.cdvi.co.uk/sites/cdviuk/files/manual/T%26C%27s%20-%20Win%20a%20trip%20to%20Paris_new.pdf" style="color: #00467f;text-decoration: none;"><strong>here</strong></a></p>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr> <!--- End Heading, Paragraph & Button Section -->


                <table class="main-table" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Verdana;color: #00467f;font-size: 12px;width: 100%;max-width: 610px;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #FFF;border-radius: 6px;">
                  <tr style="height: 60px;">
                    <td class="b-t b-r" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;border-top: 3px solid #00467f;border-right: 3px solid #00467f;">01628531300</td>
                    <td class="b-t" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;border-top: 3px solid #00467f;">
                      <ul class="social" style="list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/CDVIUK/" style="color: #00467f;text-decoration: none;"><img src="facebook.png" style="max-width: 30px;margin-bottom: 0;padding-bottom: 0;"></a></li>
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><a href="https://twitter.com/CDVIUK" style="color: #00467f;text-decoration: none;"><img src="twitter.png" style="max-width: 30px;margin-bottom: 0;padding-bottom: 0;"></a></li>
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cdvi-uk/" style="color: #00467f;text-decoration: none;"><img src="linkedin.png" style="max-width: 30px;margin-bottom: 0;padding-bottom: 0;"></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td class="b-t b-l" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;border-top: 3px solid #00467f;border-left: 3px solid #00467f;">
                      <a href="wwww.cdvi.co.uk" style="color: #00467f;text-decoration: none;">www.cdvi.co.uk</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

</table></table></div></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather than us having to copy/paste and try and run this code it would be useful to see the output you get as well as the sample you are trying to duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The max-width property you set on the inline-styles for the tables does not work in Outlook. Therefore the tables get 100% width of the parent which is the body of the mail.

You can try the following trick:

Suppose you want the centered div with max-width of 610px. You create a table, set the width to 100%. The table has three cells in a row. Set the width of the center TD to 610.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td width="610">Content with a maximum width of 610.
    </td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
```

Here's a [Link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/email-client/outlook-2007-16/) with an nice overview which css properties are not supported in outlook and other email clients.